# multiple dynamic class ids with select-option using change function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get class id for a dynamic table rows, the first row is working perfectly when it's selected, but the other rows are being fetched from java-scripts and are not working.

i.e. I can't get the class ids from the rows that is fetching from the java-script table row.

```js
//this is jquery function am using....
 $('#course_code').click(function(){
      var course_id = $('#course_code').val();
      if(course_id != '')
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url('Undergraduate_pg/fetch_course_code'); ?>",
          method:"POST",
          data:{course_id:course_id},
          success:function(data){
           
            $('#course_cod').val(data);
          }
        })
      }
    })

//this is the javascript table rows that is loading dynamically using click button..
function addrows(){
    var row = ($('.detail tr').length-0)+1;
    var tr = '<tr>' +
'<th>'+row+'</th>' +


'<td><select class="form-control course_code" id="course_code" name="course_code[]" required><option value="" selected="selected">Select Course Code</option><?php if (isset($pos)) { ?><?php foreach ($pos as $row) { ?>
  echo "<option> <?php echo $row->course_code; ?></option>";<?php } } ?></select></td>' +

'<td><select class="form-control course_title" id="Title"  name="course_title[]" required><option value="" selected="selected">Select Course Title</option><?php if (isset($pos)) { ?><?php foreach ($pos as $row) { ?>
  echo "<option> <?php echo $row->course_title; ?></option>";<?php } } ?></select></td>' +

'<td><input type="number" class="form-control unit_elect" id="course_units"  name="course_unit[]" value="" required></td>' +

'<td><select class="form-control course_status" id="course_status"  name="course_status[]" required><option value="" selected="selected">Select Course Status</option><?php if (isset($pos)) { ?><?php foreach ($pos as $row) { ?>
  echo "<option> <?php echo $row->course_status; ?></option>";<?php } } ?></select></td>' +


 '<td colspan="3"><a class="btn btn-danger remove" >X</a></td>'+ 
'</tr>';

$('.detail').append(tr);
    
  }

</script>




//i expect both static row and the dynamic row should be working once selected..
```

```html
<!--this is the html code.. note, only this is working....-->
<tbody class="detail">

<td>1</td>
<td><select class="form-control course_code" id="course_code"  name="course_code" required>
  <option value="">--Select Course Code--</option>
                        <?php if (isset($pos)) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($pos as $row) { ?>
  

                        echo "<option value="<?php echo $row->course_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->course_code; ?></option>";
                    <?php } } ?>
                 </select>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control course_cod" id="course_cod"  name="course_code[]" required>
 </td>
```

I expect both static row and the dynamic row should be working once selected.

Comment: First: there is no need to write in bold. Second, what do you mean by `class id`? Third you will run into a problem when you run your function `addrows()` since then you will have multiple elements with the same id `course_code`

Comment: i mean the class name "course_code"

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem, cos the addrows() function will generate multiple class name.. Or its can still work if there is a way i can locate the class name using "tr.find" function for select option..